# Using printf %q to make a quoted string usable as shell script input

Tags: linux, bash, printf, double-quotes, single-quotes

Within a bash script, I am trying to append a command string that is single and double quoted to a file (`.profile`).

I would like to use `echo` and then `>>` the command to `.profile`. Of course, I am open to any solution that works.

The command I would like to use is `echo "curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"PHONENUMBER","value2":"MESSAGE"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/TRIGGER/with/key/KEY &> /dev/null" >> .profile` but clearly this doesn't work within my bash script.

I am not clear on how `printf %q` works and don't understand how to apply it to my problem.

I have tried this

```
`CMDSTRING='curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '`
`CMDSTRING=${CMDSTRING}"'"`
`CMDSTRING=${CMDSTRING}'{"value1":"+PHONENUMBER","value2":"MESSAGE"}'`
`CMDSTRING=${CMDSTRING}"'"`
`CMDSTRING=${CMDSTRING}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/TRIGGER/with/key/KEY &> /dev/null'`

`echo $CMDSTRING`
```

Comment: Happy to see the light and do it the “right” way. I thought this would be quick and dirty but it’s now been slow, ugly and painful. What approach do you suggest will work?

Comment: BTW, if your message is coming from an untrusted source, it'd be a bit safer to use `jq` or another JSON-syntax-aware tool to format it for inclusion; that way a message that contains a literal `"` won't escape its quoting and be able to add extra payload arguments. (I don't know IFTTT's API, but if it supports callbacks, those arguments could potentially even be malicious).

Comment: re: edit, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) on why `echo $var` is always buggy (needs to be `echo "$var"`). And I'm hoping the backticks are just a formatting error; you'd never want them in your actual code.

Comment: BTW, also note that all-caps variable names are in the namespace used by the shell and POSIX-specified utilities themselves, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to conflict. (We get a lot of folks with problems because they ran `for PATH in ...`, whereas `for path in ...` complies with the standard's recommendations and doesn't inadvertently change how the shell operates). See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a single namespace.

Comment: BTW, note also that `printf '%q'` generates code that's safe for evaluation *by bash*, but not necessarily safe for evaluation by *all POSIX-compliant shells*. That makes it the right tool for generating content in `.bash_profile` (if you *were* actually using previously-unknown values), but the wrong tool for `.profile` (which can be used by shells other than bash).

Comment: Take a look at how a value with newlines is formatted by `%q`, f/e -- you'll see it becomes an ANSI-C-quoted string. bash and ksh can parse those correctly, but dash (as of current releases, since as of today that syntax hasn't yet been adopted into the POSIX sh standard) can't.

Comment: ...for the same reason, you shouldn't use `&>` in `.profile` at all, either; it isn't POSIX-standardized functionality. Write it out the long way: `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Agreed, but how do you ensure that the confirmation that the IFTTT command was successful was not displayed to the user?

Comment: Need I repeat myself? `>/dev/null 2>&1` first redirects stdout to `/dev/null`, then makes stderr point to the same location as stdout. It thus has the same effect as `&>/dev/null`, without relying on nonstandardized extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Using `printf '%q'` to generate `.profile` content looks something like the following:

```
{
  printf '%q ' \
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -d '{"value1":"PHONENUMBER","value2":"MESSAGE"}' \
      https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/TRIGGER/with/key/KEY
  printf '%s\n' "&>/dev/null" 
} >> .profile
```

Note that you *cannot* use the `%q` format string if you want `&>/dev/null` to be parsed as syntax, since by its very nature it formats everything it's passed to be parsed as data.

Thus, we use `printf '%q ' "command name" "first argument" ...` for the actual command itself, and format the redirection out-of-band.

---

That said, note that there's *value* to the above only if you're substituting variables from an untrusted source (rather than hardcoding them as in the example), and are worried about invalid values being abused for command injection. If you're truly just appending a constant string to the end of a file, a quoted heredoc will let you build more natural-looking shell quoting manually (indeed, as you've already done!), and pass it through verbatim:

```
cat >>.profile <<'EOF'
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"value1":"PHONENUMBER","value2":"MESSAGE"}' \
  https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/TRIGGER/with/key/KEY &> /dev/null
EOF
```

Here, everything between the `<<'EOF'` and the `EOF` are passed through exactly-as-given, *including* quotes and parameter expansions the shell might otherwise try to interpret.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give that a try.

Comment: The values in CAPS are obscured for this post but are constants in actuality. This is part of a lab I am building for graduate Cybersecurity students so it’s a closed, known, group. They need to find this compromise.

Comment: If everything is constant, there isn't a reason to use `printf %q` at all; its purpose is to take contents that are only dynamically known and find a way to format them as literals that can't be interpreted as code. If you're writing those literals as a human with good knowledge of the language syntax, you can already prevent them from being parsed as non-literal manually.

Comment: With that in mind is there an even easier way to append the command string to the .profile file?

Comment: That's the heredoc approach I showed in the second half of my answer.

Comment: Thank you @charles-duffy. Let me try all your suggestions.